# How to deal with null cell during a SqlBulkCopy from Excel

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel

I have a method that loads data from Excel and uses a `SqlBulkCopy` to insert it into a SQL Server table.

The problem is that one of the column in Excel can be empty string, and that column is mapped to a `MONEY` column in SQL Server.

I would like to default empty string to NULL or even 0 if possible.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a ternary

```
myColumn ? myColumn : 0;
```

We could also use a lot more detail from your question. Please provide code.